# Getting a popup "not supported in private and guest mode" when trying to browse a file from edge browser through selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Getting a popup "not supported in private and guest mode" when trying to browse a file from edge browser (Version 121.0.2277.128) through selenium.

I need to browse file through selenium avoiding this popup as my test cases are getting failed